# Error while running TestNG from command Prompt

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I have created a Testng.xml and tried executing it from the command propmt which is giving me the following error after executing the command D:\hg\projecttest>java org.testng.TestNG %ProjectPath%\TestNG.xml

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
```

The same TestNg.xml is working correctly from eclipse. Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to upgrade the selenium to the latest one, or downgrade firefox to an older one. Possible selenium doesn't support that version of firefox you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have tried executing same testNG.xml file from eclipse and it is running fine for the same firefox version.